# Adding diagonal borders to bottom/top of div element?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm looking for the best way to add a diagonal border to the bottom of a div element. Preferably in a way so it would also work responsively.

This image is an example of how I would want it to look:
[image]

The dark part is the header of my website and the white part is where the content will start. So the diagonal lines will act like a seperator.

I made a little example but it's not really working yet: http://jsfiddle.net/ckknu2tr/

I'm using 2 different divs with a border, one for the left and one for the right side, code example:

```
.borderright {
    line-height: 0%;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 400px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: For your case, you could make use of angled linear gradients as background. Have a look at this thread and it would help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317427/three-colors-angled-background-color/30317703#30317703

Comment: You could also have a look at this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive) for a variety of approaches to create angled sides which are responsive. It does one half while you would have to do the other side of it.

Comment: @Harry thank you for the answer!

Comment: Glad to be of help @colin :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use SVG for this. Below is a short example, which can probably be simplified, I use SVG very rarely and am not that proficient with it.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/XxGffrU.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
  margin: 0;
}
#your_div {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}
#back {
  position: relative;
  top: -99px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="your_div">
  <svg id="back" viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M 0,4 L 45,8 50,5 55,8 100,4 100,10 0,10 z" style="fill: white;"></path>
    <path d="M 0,0 L 45,8 55,8 100,0 100,10 0,10 z" style="fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```